# onClick event never fires in React Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components, this

I have a React-Redux application and I'm having issues launching a function on component click. When the logout button is clicked, it should trigger `onClick={this.handleLogout}`. However, Redux dev tools and adding a console log in the `handleLogout` prove that the function never executes.

Here are the two components, a standard navigation bar and a custom button component. I've left out some imports to shorten the code.

## Navigation Bar

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
  handleLogout = () => {
    this.props.logOut();
    this.props.history.push("/login");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <span className="nav-left">
          <Link className="light" to="/">
            Home
          </Link>
        </span>
        <span className="nav-right">
          {this.props.authenticated ? (
            <>
              <Button to="/account">Account</Button>
              <Button onClick={this.handleLogout} buttonStyle="danger">
                Log Out
              </Button>
            </>
          ) : (
            <Button to="/login">Login</Button>
          )}
        </span>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

Navigation.propTypes = {
  authenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  logOut: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

## Button

```
export default class Button extends Component {
  state = {
    classList: classNames({
      button: true,
      button_accent: this.props.buttonStyle === "accent",
      button_danger: this.props.buttonStyle === "danger"
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="button_container">
        <div
          className={classNames({
            button_wrapper: true,
            center: !this.props.left && !this.props.right,
            left: this.props.left,
            right: this.props.right
          })}
        >
          {
            this.props.to ? (
              this.props.regular ? (
                <a href={this.props.to} className={this.state.classList}>
                  {this.props.children}
                </a>
              ) : (
                <Link to={this.props.to} className={this.state.classList}>
                  {this.props.children}
                </Link>
              )
            ) : (
              <span className={this.state.classList}>
                {this.props.children}
              </span>              
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Component Dev Tools
[component dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr0ws.png)

Comment: I guess you need to bind the `handleLogout` callback to `this` in order to make `this` work as expected. Read further here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: @norbitrial No luck. Although in the Component Dev Tools it now says `bound handleLogout` instead... [See pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Y3b3v6GY)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass onClick to the span that represents a button without a link

```html
export default class Button extends Component {
  state = {
    classList: classNames({
      button: true,
      button_accent: this.props.buttonStyle === "accent",
      button_danger: this.props.buttonStyle === "danger"
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="button_container">
        <div
          className={classNames({
            button_wrapper: true,
            center: !this.props.left && !this.props.right,
            left: this.props.left,
            right: this.props.right
          })}
        >
          {
            this.props.to ? (
              this.props.regular ? (
                <a href={this.props.to} className={this.state.classList}>
                  {this.props.children}
                </a>
              ) : (
                <Link to={this.props.to} className={this.state.classList}>
                  {this.props.children}
                </Link>
              )
            ) : (
              <span onClick={this.props.onClick} className={this.state.classList}>
                {this.props.children}
              </span>              
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So... `onClick` has to be on a DOM element? Is that my issue? It can't be on a component, in other words?

Comment: Sure, the onClick event just works on a DOM Element, if you use onClick over a React Component react it's going to think that you are passing a prop to that component